# Drupal8 Geolocation module - How to use in my local system?

Tags: geolocation, drupal-8

I am using Geo-location module in my local system, not able to ping to client location. It does not allow access block.It provides me the error(No location data found. Reason: PERMISSION_DENIED.)

On using the Glocation module in (SimplyTestMe), it works fine.

Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide some sort of API token with your request?

Comment: Already the default Google API is present with that module, using it worked in simplytestme. If i want to work, what steps to follow.